# Could not connect to debugger on port xxxxx for rails debugging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aptana

I installed Aptana for eclipse on Windows 7. When I try to debug a RoR app, it throws the following error:

`An internal error occurred during: "Launching myRailsApp". Could not connect to debugger on port 50671`

The console shows this:

```
Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.16, ruby-debug-base 0.11) listens on 127.0.0.1:50308
Fatal exception in DebugThread loop: The requested service provider could not be loaded or initialized. - socket(2)
Backtrace:
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:135:in `initialize'
 from: C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:135:in `new'
 from: C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:135:in `block in start_control'
```

The server was started successfully at localhost:3000

I just want to get the debugger up and running so I can set breakpoints, etc.

What would be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have something else, like another project, running on port 50671?  This error is usually thrown when the port is already in use.  Try killing Aptana and restarting.

Comment: I restarted so many times. Im downloading netbeans now. I give up on aptana.

Comment: go to the command prompt and type 'netstat -a' and see if anything else is running on that port

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your port is running on 50308, and your IDE trying to connect to 50671.
Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.16, ruby-debug-base 0.11) listens on 127.0.0.1:50308

Do you have ruby-debug-ide gem installed ??